# Search Task Scheduler Library

Tags: windows-8.1, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

I've inherited a server with several hundred scheduled tasks. There's no consistent naming scheme, so finding some particular task that performs some particular action is rather tedious.

Is there any way to create a filter on Task Scheduler's library pane so I can limit my manual search to entries that have some key word in the task name?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Is there any way to create a filter on Task Scheduler's library pane

I don't think it is possible to create a filter in Task Scheduler.

However, you can use explorer's search facilities to do the filtering, as the scheduled tasks can be found in `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks`.

Just search for a string that is part of the task name.

Now you have the folder names containing the tasks (which mirror the names in the hierarchy in Task Scheduler).

Example (searching for VAIO):

[image]

[image]

Notes:

- The tasks are in files named after the trigger ID in the file. Example:

> ```
> <Triggers>
>   <LogonTrigger id="VAIO Care">
>     <Enabled>true</Enabled>
>     <Delay>PT5M</Delay>
>   </LogonTrigger>
> </Triggers>
> ```

- The corresponding task file name is `VAIO Care`
- The files are XML formatted files.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a ton. I was hoping there would be a way to do something similar within the actual task manager application, but I guess that's just not a feature.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with Powershell.

Example:

> Get-ScheduledTask | where {$_.settings.waketorun}

Got this information from [here](https://winaero.com/blog/find-scheduled-tasks-which-wake-up-your-windows-10-pc/)

Here's my results: 
[powershell results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEfNl.png)

I'm assuming from the format of this command that you should also be able to filter with any other setting from the tasks settings window you have in mind. Just search google for other possible commands you may need.

[Here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/01/12/use-powershell-to-show-results-of-scheduled-tasks/) are some other ideas you may be able to start with. Some of his ideas include ways to find tasks with a specific name.

I know this question is very old, but it showed on google when I was having this issue, so I thought I'd input my 2 cents for anyone finding this later.